# Win7 Windows Explorer sometimes display directory name in address bar in lower case

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Win7 Windows Explorer **sometimes** display directory name in address bar in lower case.
When pressing back button, the directory name in address bar return to exact letter case.

Why this happens? Is it a bug? **sometimes** happen so may not be reproduced every time.

How to disable such "feature"?

Comment: Create a new user account and check if the issue recurs in the newly created account.